# Python - capture one leg of multidimensional dictionary and change to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional dictionary that I believe I only need the last array inside to be converted into a pandas dataframe, the first three don't appear to hold any relevant information. I don't know how to access this though, how do you make this conversion?

If I use scipy to load the .mat file like `mat = scipy.io.loadmat('mill.mat')` I get this result (this is a partial, it's long but you can see the heading names):

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: Tue Nov 27 15:59:45 2007',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'mill': array([[(array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[0]], dtype=uint8), array([[2]], dtype=uint8), array([[1.5]]), array([[0.5]]), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[-0.01708984],
        [ 0.26367188],
        [ 0.20751953],
        ...,
        [-0.80810547],
        [-0.73242188],
        [-0.57617188]]), array([[0.625     ],
        [0.81054688],
        [0.78125   ],
        ...,
        [1.38183594],
        [1.30371094],
        [1.52832031]]), array([[0.078125  ],
        [0.08544922],
        [0.078125  ],
        ...,
        [0.27587891],
        [0.52246094],
        [0.37841797]]), array([[0.31494141],
        [0.30151367],
        [0.30395508],
        ...,
        [0.3125    ],
        [0.31738281],
        [0.3112793 ]]), array([[0.08728027],
        [0.0982666 ],
        [0.09216309],
        ...,
```

It looks to me like `mill` is the only thing worth capturing. How to I turn just this section into a pandas DF?

Comment: Start with `res = mat['mill']`, then try `pd.DataFrame(res)`, and if that doesn't work, look at `res.shape` and experiment with `res.reshape()`

Comment: You're idea of `mat['mill'] does pull out that single leg from the dictionary. I do not know how to reshape this though, there's no keys as far as I can tell, it's just an array of arrays? The only value `.reshape()` seems to take as an argument is 167, which just returns the original

Comment: Yup, looks like `mat['mill']` is an array of arrays. What is its shape, i.e, what is the output of `res.shape`? Ideally, it's possible to massage it into a 2-dimensional shape that can be passed to the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor.

Comment: `res.shape` = `(1, 167)`

Comment: For what it's worth I believe there's supposed to be 13 columns all together. Obviously they are not all equal tho